# continue button gives error in magento checkout page

Tags: checkout

My website is http://www.hbherb.com/ and in the onepage checkout I Can't go into next step continue button is not working, I have checked in the firbug and it gives error (Error: "throw $continue" is deprecated, use "return" instead).

[image]

Comment: "Try including jQuery + plugins first, calling jQuery.noConflict(), then including prototype"

Comment: Have you checked that jQuery is actually included and using the correct scope? As kaska pointed out you may need to set the correct scope ($ vs. jquery) for jquery using the jQuery.noConflict() function.

Comment: I'm very new to magento, I dont understand what's the problem with js can you please help me

Comment: what I need to do exactlly to solve this problem, can you guide me step by step